# Windows Disc Space

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-upgrade

I've made a clean install with the new Windows 10, from the offered options I've selected clean start and deleting all the files from the previous installation. After the installation, my disc space is used as before the installation. 
How can I make sure that all the files are deleted and at the same time clean the space I need?

Comment: During install you are asked if you want to keep files or not, choosing to Not keep anything is a clean install and no old files are left behind, this is as minimal disk space to be used.

Comment: Show hidden files and folders and check the content of your C drive. If you see a folder called Windows.old, then there's a good chance your old files are still there and you'll have to unlock this folder in order to gain some free space. Run Disk Cleanup as admin will let you see where you can gain that space.

Answer (score 0):

After running [Disk Cleanup](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4026616/windows-10-disk-cleanup) to identify and remove [left over System Files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_Cleanup), you can overwrite all unused disk space to make sure files can't be recovered short of National Means with the [cipher](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/cipher) CLI [command](https://ss64.com/nt/cipher.html), as explained at https://www.thewindowsclub.com/cipher-command-line-tool-windows.

```
cipher /w:driveletter:\foldername
```